# Anchor Tag href functions

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am trying to create a function that finds the id of an element that an anchor tag directs to, and attach a class to that element. I need this to be vanilla js not jquery.

For Example:

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>

<div> Destination </div>
<div> Destination #2 </div>
```

The idea would be that once you click on the anchor tag that it would take you to the div and attach a class to that div to initiate a function.

The script that I've written runs for loops that add the values of the href attribute and the id attribute from javascript objects. See Below:

```
var rooms = [
{
id: 1,
name: Example,
},
{
id:2,
name: Example #2,
}
]

         for ( x in rooms ) {
           var i = document.getElementById("firstDiv");
           var a = document.createElement("a");
           i.appendChild(a);
           a.href = "#" + rooms[x].id;
           a.innerHTML += rooms[x].name + "<br>";
           a.classList.add("show");
          
        }

        var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
        for ( i = 0; i < rect.length; i++ ) {
           rect[i].setAttribute("id", rooms[i].id);
        }
```

Output:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
<a href="#1"> Example </a>
<a href="#2"> Example #2 </a>
</div>

<div id="1"> Destination </div>
<div id="2"> Destination #2 </div>
```

The function below is an example of what I want the function to do for each corresponding div when an a tag is clicked.

```
function attach() {
var div = document.getElementById(rooms[i].id);
div.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Any advice on how to properly write this function for my particular needs. Would a for loop be best for this or an if/else statement. I've tried both but neither has worked.

Please let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: Your initial HTML sample does not include an anchors.

Comment: The anchor tags are created by the first for loop

Comment: Why are you adding a BR in your anchor tag? Use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you are asking about. See comments inline.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // First, check to see if it was an anchor that was clicked
  // in the document
  if(event.target.nodeName === "A"){
    // If so, add a class to the target 
    // Get the href attribute and strip off the "#", then find that element and toggle the class
  document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("href").replace("#","")).classList.toggle("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="firstDiv">
  <a href="#one"> Example </a>
  <a href="#two"> Example #2 </a>
</div>

<div id="one"> Destination </div>
<div id="two"> Destination #2 </div>
```

Comment: I think this might be what I am looking for. Would I be able to replace "A" in the if statement with a js object like this one rooms[i].id? Or would I need to put the if statement inside some sort of for loop? Sorry I am a javascript noob

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll("#firstDiv a");

for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        var div = document.getElementById(rooms[i].id);
        div.classList.toggle("active");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there you just need to add an onclick property for the anchor tag now you can or cannot use the third attach function.I am including both implementations for your reference.

```
for ( x in rooms ) {
       var i = document.getElementById("firstDiv");
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       i.appendChild(a);
       a.href = "#" + rooms[x].id;
       a.innerHTML += rooms[x].name + "<br>";
       a.classList.add("show");
       a.onClick=`document.getElementById(${rooms[x].id}).classList.toggle("active")`;
    }
```

If you want to have a dedicated function your loop becomes

```
for ( x in rooms ) {
       var i = document.getElementById("firstDiv");
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       i.appendChild(a);
       a.href = "#" + rooms[x].id;
       a.innerHTML += rooms[x].name + "<br>";
       a.classList.add("show");
       a.onClick=`attach(${rooms[x].id})`;
    }
```

Your attach function then becomes:

```
function attach(id) {
 var div = document.getElementById(id);
 div.classList.toggle("active");
  }
```

Do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Only**

This is a bit off-topic but you can use the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector to set the style of the corresponding id *without JS*.

```css
/* element with an id matching the URL fragment */
:target {
   background: gold;  
}

/* you can combine target with other selectors */
#c:target {
   background: orange
}



/* just a bit of styling */
a,div {
  padding: .5rem;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">Link to A</a>
<a href="#b">Link to B</a>
<a href="#c">Link to C</a>
<a href="#d">Link to D</a>

<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
<div id="d">D</div>
```